# App to app video calling for android

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, pubnub, android-sinch-api

I tried Pubnub API but it does not work since they updated the API but did not update their documentation. I have also tried using Sinch SDK, and followed the 
tutorial :
 https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/video-call-android-tutorial/#
I loved the tutorial and the app also worked but there is so much of disturbance in the call that audio cannot be heard properly.

How can I make a video calling app?

Comment: `i need a tutorial` this is wrong place to search for the tutorial. SO rules declare such questions as off-topic.

Comment: Just an easy to understand API suggestion would do.